# Problem with using OfficeRuntime.storage in existing Excel Add-in

Tags: storage, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm trying to share some data between my existing Excel Add-in taskpane and newly added custom-functions. When I'm trying to set/get value I get "NotImplemented: Not implemented." error.

I'm referencing this package in my taskpane page:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

And I use storage in my taskpane this way:

```js
OfficeRuntime.storage.setItem('someData', someData)
    .then((result) =>
    {
      console.log(result);
    }, (error) =>
    {
      console.log('Store error: ');
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I also use Typescript in my add-in, so I've added

```
"@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.7"
```

package for types.
I've seen in some examples OfficeRuntime.AsyncStorage used, but I can't use it, as it isn't available in the IntelliSense.

Also I want to add that I have Excel version 1904 (Build 11601.20204) and Windows 10 version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay. I believe we have resolved that issue. Can you try again?

If it does repro still, please let us know!

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/522

Comment: I've tried, and OfficeRuntime.storage seems to work between the TaskPane and Custom Functions, thank you! ;)